# order dependency (topological sort) with input of string

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, topological-sort

https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-ii/
The question is similar to this one but instead, it has input of string instead of numbers. The following is the classes and the sample test case and signatures. I am just wondering how do i deal with the input of string

```
import java.util.*;
class Order{
    String order = "";
    public Order(String string){
        this.order = string;
    }
}
class OrderDependency{
    Order cur;
    Order pre;
    public OrderDependency(Order o1, Order o2){
        cur = o1;
        pre = o2;
    }
}
public class Order_Dependency {
    public static List<Order> getOrderList(List<OrderDependency> orderDependencies){

    ***Code Starts Here***

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Order o1 = new Order("A");
        Order o2 = new Order("B");
        Order o3 = new Order("C");
        Order o4 = new Order("D");
        OrderDependency od1 = new OrderDependency(o1, o2);
        OrderDependency od2 = new OrderDependency(o2, o3);
        OrderDependency od3 = new OrderDependency(o3, o4);
        List<OrderDependency> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(od1);
        list.add(od2);
        list.add(od3);

        for (Order o : getOrderList(list)){
            System.out.println(o.order);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/13873/two-ac-solution-in-java-using-bfs-and-dfs-with-explanation
This is a great answer for the question with int input. How to convert this to above case tho? (BFS)